# I work on a company office with a remote team, does it counts as a remote experience?

Tags: resume, remote-work

Currently I'm working on a company that has a office in my city but my team on the company is based on another office.

The company has other employees here but they work in different projects.

Does this counts as a remote work experience? Should I list it in my resume?

Comment: I'd rather put it as "Experience of coordinating and working with remote team" rather than "remote work experience" if I want to put it into my CV. IMO "remote work experience" isn't really something outstandingly positive to be put into CV skills/experiences section unless there's too much space to fill.

Comment: Do you already distinguish your remote and non-remote experience on your resume?

Comment: Why do you want to specify whether experience is remote or not? Are you applying to remote positions?

Comment: @DavidK Yes, Im looking for a remote job in the future,

Comment: @sf02 no, because this is my first "remote" experience

Answer (score 6):

> Does this counts as a remote work experience?

No, because you're not working remotely, separate from everyone else. Your team is just working in a separate office, that's all.

But in any case:

> Should I list it in my resume?

I don't see how this is a particularly valuable thing to list on a resume. I'd just glance past that as "fluff". It *may* have some relevance if the setup at the company you're applying to is near enough exactly the same, but even then it's weak. Much better to emphasise the relevant skills that you have instead.

Comment: Im looking for a remote position atm

Answer (score 2):

The most defining parts of remote work (in my experience working remotely) are

- **You don't work in an office.** You're responsible for finding an area (and/or mindset) that allows you to focus and be productive, and shield yourself from distractions. Don't underestimate the difficulty of this. Sitting at your kitchen table is a *lot* different from sitting at an office desk (for me at least), and requires different techniques to tune out the environment and be productive.
- **You need to be excellent at communicating with a team who you can't physically talk to.** Since you will likely never see the people you're working with in person, you'll need to be proactive at communicating via whatever messaging/calling/collaboration tools your workplace uses.

It sounds like you have experience at the second of those points, but not the first. As such **I wouldn't say you have experience as a remote worker**, but I think it's definitely worth highlighting in your CV and cover letter that you have experience working with a team in a different location to yourself.

Experience as a remote worker is usually listed as a requirement for remote positions (as you're no doubt aware), and with any job application it's always worthwhile to draw attention to similar experience when you don't have everything they're looking for.

If you're finding that's not enough, then you could investigate whether your company would allow you to work from home. Even one week a month over several months could get you to the point where you can list yourself as having remote working experience, and be able to talk in interviews about the challenges and how you overcame them.